# Wget change domain name

Tags: wget, ghost-blog

I am trying to convert a ghost website running on localhost:2368. I am using buster, which uses wget to download files from localhost:2368 and turn it into a static website. My problem is that wget makes all links with reference as localhost:2368.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://localhost:2368/assets/styles/style.css">
```

I have identified the buster code that calls wget when generating the static website:

```
if arguments['generate']:
    command = ("wget "
               "--recursive "             # follow links to download entire site
               "--convert-links "         # make links relative
               "--page-requisites "       # grab everything: css / inlined images
               "--no-parent "             # don't go to parent level
               "--directory-prefix {1} "  # download contents to static/ folder
               "--no-host-directories "   # don't create domain named folder
               "--restrict-file-name=unix "  # don't escape query string
               "{0}").format(arguments['--domain'], static_path)
```

I use py -m buster generate --domain=localhost:2368 to generate the website. Is there any way for me to generate these files with references to my website? example instead of localhost:2368 it should be abc.com.

Comment: Replace `http://localhost:2368` with `http://example.com` in all your files?

Comment: Thanks, But there are too many posts for that.

Comment: I'm thinking it's easier to automate a string replacement than to change wget.

Comment: I was going to do that as a last resort, but fortunately managed to get a fix. Hopefully, this thread helps people who get stuck here in future.

Comment: https://fdezromero.com/how-i-host-this-static-ghost-blog-on-github-pages-with-wget/

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues with the buster GitHub repo that didn't account for this. I found a pulled repo with some fixes and another very specific pull request on the original repo. Merging the pull request with the files from the pulled request helped fix this issue for me. For those interested in a working buster repo for Ghost Static Pages Please refer below:

Refer to this [pull request](https://github.com/axitkhurana/buster/pull/67/commits/d67304251484d148abcceb2018902c6a3f51b322)  This pull request fixes the css versioning issue for Windows. 
And this working [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/joshgerdes/buster) to see the issues that were fixed. This fix allowed us to pass in --new-domain option which is used to create links.

Apparently, the existing repo is no longer supported.